# bind home and other folders to casper-rw

Tags: mount, partition, bind, persistence

I use an USB key with a casper-rw partition but Ubuntu only binds `/var/log-crash` to casper-rw, the rest of linux files are non-persistant. But i want to have nearly all consistent, like an normal installation of Ubuntu.

So how to bind/mount folders in that way ?

Comment: How did you prepare the USB key to make it persistent live? Which version of Ubuntu? Which tool did you use? I need this informatiion to give relevant advice. Otherwise I can only say that [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) works with all current versions of Ubuntu, but it is a linux tool. If you must make the USB key persistent live in Windows, you must use another tool, and it depends on the version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please tell us how you prepared the USB key to make it persistent live! I will help us help you. -- After some own tests, I would think that there is no boot option `persistent` in your system. Please add it near the end of the linux line in the grub menuentry. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy#Edit_grub.cfg). But if you have a cloned system, you can do it [this way instead](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/minp/details). Look at the `sed` command.

Comment: In fact i didn't have much time to consecrate to this problem so i basically just run a script stored in `/var/log/` at each restart who perpetually reinstall all the programs and parameters

It's the last actual version of Ubuntu and i make it persistent with UUI if i remember and i deleted the casper of UUI to make a real partition full casper. It partially works but only for the binded folder that i quoted

Comment: I suggest that next time that you make a persistent live drive you do it in a way that will give you persistence the right way (without having to run a script in `/var/log`). See the following link: [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: In fact I can't play with USB drives because I don't have any hard drives or things like that, I only work on that USB key

Comment: When I write drive, I mean any kind of drive: USB key (alias pendrive), SSD, HDD, memory card. But yes, I agree, you need another one in order to play with new systems.